# using roles in asp.net with windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, security-roles

I need to use the Roles.GetUsersInRole(role) method to get usernames that should receive an email when an event happens.
I am using Windows authentication.

In my web Config:

```
     <system.web> 
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <identity impersonate="false" />
        <roleManager enabled="true"
                 defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>
...
      </system.web>
```

everything compiles fine however when I call that method I get this error:

{"The configured Role Provider (WindowsTokenRoleProvider) relies upon Windows authentication to determine the groups that the user is allowed to be a member of. ASP.NET Role Manager cannot be used to manage Windows users and groups. Please use the SQLRoleProvider if you would like to support custom user/role assignment."}

Is this a configuration issue?
I need to continue to use windows authentication, however I also need to be able to get usernames from the groups.

If there is no configuration setting to accomplish this is there any kind of work around that would get me this functionality?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use SQL Role Provider to grant access to the MVC Controller in your web application. You can also show / hide the parts of a view using User.IsInRole Method (String) which returns a boolean type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working sample ASP.NET MVC 4 application that uses windows authentication with SQL Server Role Provider.

In the `web.config`file under `<system.web>` section:

```
<roleManager  enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name ="SqlRoleProvider"
   type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
   connectionStringName="AspNetMembershipConnString"
   applicationName="MembershipAndRoleProviderSample"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

This tells the asp.net runtime to use Sql role provider and indicates which connection string to use to locate the database.

Because we are using SQL Role Provider, we need a database where users and roles are stored. To create the database use `aspnet_regsql.exe` command (on my windows 10 pro machine its under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319) which allows to create the schema that holds the users and roles.

**Note:** When creating the schema through this tool, make sure the database name is the same as given in your connection string in the web.config file (coming up next).

Back to the web.config file add the connection string

```
 <connectionStrings>    
    <add connectionString="DATA SOURCE = PersonalLaptop\SQLEXPRESS2014; INITIAL CATALOG = AspNetMembership; INTEGRATED SECURITY = SSPI;"
          name="AspNetMembershipConnString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Make sure the name of connection string is the same as the one in the sql role provider section.

**Note:** You dont need the membership provider because you are using Integrated Windows Authentication mode.

**Create a role and add a user**

There are 2 ways to do this.

**1)** 
Open up the SQL database where `aspnet_regsql.exe` has created the tables and stored procs. Create a new record in `aspnet_Users`, `aspnet_Applications`, `aspnet_UsersInRoles` and `aspnet_Roles` tables. Since you are using the windows authentication therefore make sure that you add the windows user name (Fully Qualified Domain Name / Local User Name) in the `aspnet_Users` table.

**2)** 
In the HomeController's Index method use the code:

```
Roles.CreateRole("SuperDuperUsers");
Roles.AddUserToRole("<WindowsUserName>", "SuperDuperUsers");
```

This will create the role and the user will be added into that role for you.

I have uploaded the sample asp.net mvc 4 application [here](https://github.com/Yawarmurtaza/AspNetMembership) on github for you.

In the github repo, SqlScriptOfTheDatabase.sql file contains the schema that is created to store the users and roles and their relationship. You can use this instead of using the 
`aspnet_regsql.exe` command if you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your extremely thorough answer. Im hoping our IT staff can manage the groups through active directory. Is there a way to setup the db so that it will be updated when there is a change in AD?

Comment: @user3839756  you are welcome! Since you want to restrict the access to certain parts of your web application based upon the roles that you  define in the web.config file, it has to be a manual job. Once you have AD groups set up, you can assign a group to a particular role which will have particular access  in your web application. The mapping of AD groups and roles will have to be done manually simply because the business will decide what departments can see or edit what parts of the application. Hope this makes sense.